# C# grammar: What character is the "new line" character?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, grammar, line-endings

I am implementing my own Lexer and just had a look at how C# handles char literals: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx

*The C# char grammer is described in the link above*
It specifies that the "new line" character is not allowed as a character literal.
**But it doesn't state what the "new line" character is.**
From my perspective it could be one of the following:

1. CR + LF (windows)
2. LF (unix & mac)
3. CR (mac)
4. CR || LF || CR + LF (all of them)

Since one file could be created on f.e. mac and then be compiled on windows I tend to believe that the "new line" character matches the grammer in case 4. I remember VS asking me if I'd like to convert my line endings to match the windows line endings in some cases. Since we can decline that option it is possible to stick with whatever endings the file contains. 
Can someone confirm case 4 or tell me that I'm wrong?

Comment: I can't see any mention of newline not being allowed on that page (or its English counterpart)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen It sais (in german) **Beliebiges Zeichen außer ' (U+0027), \ (U+005C) und einem new-line-character** which translates to **Any character except ' (U+0027), \ (U+005C) and a new-line-character**

Comment: This is why`Environment.NewLine` exists.

Comment: Hmm, now I see it. Wonder what my mobile browser did first. There was no mention of that :o

Comment: @Will Environment.NewLine will return the character for the current OS wich might not be the one in the file (if the file was created on another os)

Comment: Yeah, it's confoozin tho.  I think the default option would be to use the system's newline and throw if an unexpected character sequence is found.

Comment: @Will That makes no sense in this context, as we're talking about the *language specification*, no "system" is being described, other than the language itself

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Just making a comment on the implementation.  Everybody, take it easy.  It's monday morning ffs.  I concede whatever arguments, and wish you all a good day, kind sirs.

Comment: @Will I guess time zones are a bit like operating systems. Not everybody lives/works in the same one ;D BTW only throw what you cannot handle!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, it can be either CR or LF, and a few more, according to spec:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812(v=vs.71).aspx

```
new-line-character:
    Carriage return character (U+000D)
    Line feed character (U+000A)
    Line separator character (U+2028)
    Paragraph separator character (U+2029)
```

Comment: HA! I couldn't find that spec! COOL! Then this is a C specification?

Comment: No. This is C# specification.

Comment: @NoëlWidmer The "C" is the appendix/chapter name in the specification, not the language